# Find all instances of React component by Tag name

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to write a plugin for a webpage that uses React.
I have access to `React` and `ReactDOM`.

I need to find all instances of the `PageWrapper` React component for this particular page.

I can do this using the React dev tools for Google Chrome with the search bar, but I want to be able to do this in JavaScript.

[image: PageWrapper React Dev Tools]

Is there any way of doing this in JavaScript?
Something like `FindAllInstancesOfReactComponent(tagName)` would be perfect.

Comment: Why you don't use a simple `document.querySelectorAll('ReactComponent')`?

Comment: That doesn't work because the real dom tree is using only default html tags, no custom components.

Comment: Is it your own page and React app? What's the purpose? What's PageWrapper?

Comment: I'm trying to write a plugin for discord with BetterDiscord. Discord uses React, and my plugin has access to React and ReactDOM. That's all I have to work with.

Comment: You need to hook React renderer, similarly to how React devtools work. See https://github.com/bruderstein/react-render-hook for how this can be done.

Answer (score 0):

You may try using reactDOM.

```
ReactDOM.findDOMNode(component)
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#finddomnode

Comment: Almost, but just the  other way around essentially. Need to find all instances of React nodes by component name.